# How to create a grid in ASP.NET Core MVC using C# in which we insert the record and save the whole data to the database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to create a grid or table that accepts multiple data as we do in ASP.NET webforms.

There will be a form with Name, FName, Class, and Gender fields and textbox including an Add button at the end of the form to add the data in the table/grid.

The grid/table will have the same name columns as the fields name. The grid/table will be below the form and there will be a Save button below the table/grid. When I click on the Save button then the data in table/grid should be saved in the database.

I want to try this in ASP.NET Core MVC using C# with SQL Server at its backend.

I expect the form's data should be added in the `table/grid` and then I should be able to Save the data in grid/table to Database by clicking on the Save button.

Guys, Do you have any suggestion for this?

Comment: have you tried this yourself..?what challenges are u faceing to do this.?

Comment: I tried to create it but failed as I am new to it. I haven't considered JQuery and Javascript.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=crud+operations+in+asp.net+mvc+core&rlz=1C1GCEA_enIN840IN840&oq=crud+operations+in+asp.net+mvc+core&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.8783j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 why cant you search it and learn it from this link. There are so many examples available in internet.

Comment: @AbdulBasit  can you show us code what you have tried. Please check this link
      https://hackernoon.com/asp-net-core-learn-crud-operations-in-ado-net-from-zero-to-hero-a0109ed2f8a4

Comment: @RajeshB I have searched it everywhere. I have used CRUD examples but this is different. In this question, I have mentioned creating a table/grid in which users can enter the data like 10 rows and while clicking on the save button. The data should be saved into a database.

Comment: DataTables.net is a good option

Comment: https://forums.asp.net/t/2148481.aspx?how+to+add+multiple+rows+and+save+with+a+single+button+to+save+in+database+table+in+MVC+Core 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53452180/how-to-insert-multiple-rows-database-in-asp-net-core-2-1

try these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using JQuery to get the added data list and send them to the controller.

Here is a simple demo :

Model StudentInfo and StudentViewModel

```
public class StudentInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FName { get; set; }
    public string Class { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
}

public class StudentViewModel
{
    public  List<StudentInfo> StudentInfos { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
 [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> InsertStudents([FromBody]StudentViewModel studentVM)
    {
        List<StudentInfo> model = studentVM.StudentInfos;
        _context.AddRange(model);
        int insertedRecords=await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Json(insertedRecords);

    }
```

The view

```
<table id="tblStudents" class="table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th style="width:150px">Name</th>
        <th style="width:150px">FName</th>
        <th style="width:150px">Class</th>
        <th style="width:150px">Gender</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>   
</tbody>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="txtName" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txtFName" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txtClass" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txtGender" /></td>
        <td><input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add" /></td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
<br />
<input type="button" id="btnSave" value="Save All" />
```

The javascript

```
@section Scripts
{
<script type="text/javascript">
$("body").on("click", "#btnAdd", function () {
    //Reference the Name and Country TextBoxes.
    var txtName = $("#txtName");
    var txtFName = $("#txtFName");
    var txtClass = $("#txtClass");
    var txtGender = $("#txtGender");

    //Get the reference of the Table's TBODY element.
    var tBody = $("#tblStudents > TBODY")[0];

    //Add Row.
    var row = tBody.insertRow(-1);

    //Add Name cell.
    var cell = $(row.insertCell(-1));
    cell.html(txtName.val());
    //Add FName cell.
    cell = $(row.insertCell(-1));
    cell.html(txtFName.val());
    //Add Class cell.
    cell = $(row.insertCell(-1));
    cell.html(txtClass.val());
    //Add Gender cell.
    cell = $(row.insertCell(-1));
    cell.html(txtGender.val());

    //Clear the TextBoxes.
    txtName.val("");
    txtFName.val("");
    txtClass.val("");
    txtGender.val("");
});


$("body").on("click", "#btnSave", function () {
    //Loop through the Table rows and build a JSON array.
    var students = new Array();
    $("#tblStudents TBODY TR").each(function () {
        var row = $(this);
        var student = {};
        student.Name = row.find("TD").eq(0).html();
        student.FName = row.find("TD").eq(1).html();
        student.Class = row.find("TD").eq(2).html();
        student.Gender = row.find("TD").eq(3).html();
        students.push(student);
    });

    //Populate invoice data
    var studentVM = {};
    studentVM.StudentInfos = students;

    //Send the JSON array to Controller using AJAX.
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/StudentInfoes/InsertStudents",
        data: JSON.stringify(studentVM),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (r) {
            alert(r + " record(s) inserted.");
        }
    });
});
</script>
}
```

Comment: I applied all the code and added a Save button but clicking on Save button doesn't perform any action.

Comment: Did you use the browser's developer tool to check if there is the error when clicking Save button and check if  the url in ajax is correct ? I have posted the entire code of the view , please check !

Comment: Can you send me the project files? Yes, I checked the developer tool on Chrome but the controller wasn't called.

Comment: I have uploaded the same project to GitHub https://github.com/basit-chachar/MyProjects/tree/master/TableDataIntoDatabase you can check it and please let me know if I am missing anything.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use another component , i recommend the MVC6 grid http://mvc6-grid.azurewebsites.net/

basically it use almost same syntax ,so there will be minor changes to your current code ,please check the below sample code

```
@model IEnumerable<PersonModel>

@(Html
.Grid(Model)
.Build(columns =>
{
columns.Add(model => model.Name).Titled("Name");
columns.Add(model => model.Surname).Titled("Surname");

columns.Add(model => model.Age).Titled("Age");
columns.Add(model => model.Birthday).Titled("Birth date");
columns.Add(model => model.IsWorking).Titled("Employed");

//popup part
columns.Add(model => $"<a  data-modal='' data-id=\"{model.Id}\"     href='PasswordRestUser/{model.Id}'      id=\"ss\"  asp-    action=\"PR\" asp-route-id=\"@item.Id\" class=\"btn     btn-info\" '> PR <span class='glyphicon      glyphicon-user'> </span> </a>").Encoded(false);

})
.Filterable()
.Sortable()
.Pageable()
)

<div id='myModal' class='modal fade in'>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div id='myModalContent'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

it also has many other features that will make thing easier with .netcore

Comment: who to implement rowspan here ?